# Custom Authentication Login in Django via email

Tags: python, django

I am trying to understand login methods in Django. So because I want to login with email not username. I wrote a custom authentication backend and exposed it in settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'accounts.backend.EmailAuthenticationBackend',
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

class EmailAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
  def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    try:
      user = Account.objects.get(email=email)
      if user.check_password(password):
        return user
    except user.DoesNotExist:
      pass
```

And in view `user_login` how I authenticate the user. And it's actually works. I mean kind of...

```
def user_login(request):
  next = request.GET.get("next")

  form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
    password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    login(request, user)
    if next:
      return redirect(next)

    return redirect("/")

  context = {
    "form": form
  }

  return render(request, "accounts/user_login.html", context)
```

the `authenticate()` method is returns the user. But `redirect()` is not working because in browser thinks user not logged in. I am not sure about how to handle the session part.

and custom `UserLoginForm`

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
  email = forms.CharField()
  password = forms.CharField()

  def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

    if email and password:
      user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
      if not user:
        raise forms.ValidationError("user not exist")

      if not user.check_password(password):
        raise forms.ValidationError("incorrect password")

    return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

The second issue is if `email` or `password` wrong. it doesn't raise any error.

what is the best common way to handle custom login with email.

Comment: What was the purpose of `if next` in your code?

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam if user came from `login_required` page and logged in then I want to send the user to that page again. if there is `next="/blabla"` if not then directly redirect user to main page "/"

Comment: I think the problem of no redirecting is in that the form is not valid

Comment: because you said it doesn't even redirect to `"/"`.

Comment: Am I right yvl?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out and I did `else:` act too, but it doesn't change anything. so I am still trying to figure that out. @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the reason, it doesn't redirect is you've assigned the
   `request.GET.get("next")` into `nxt` variable, however you are
   checking the `next` variable for redirecting, probably you should
   change the variable `nxt` to `next`.
2. The reason that it doesn't raise any error is, you've put `try and except` to handle the thrown errors in the `authenticate()` method and you just put `pass` in the `excpetion` part. If you want the error to be thrown, just remove the `try and except` part from `authenticate()`.

Comment: sorry about the typo. I already fixed in the code, but forgot to update here. It still not working.